# How to get the data from a <td> using EJS with modals

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, ejs

I'm trying to display in a modal window some user emails but I can't figure out why I get only the first email even if the modal divs were declared in the forEach()
Code snippet below:

```html
<div class="row" class="text-center">
  <div class="col-11">

    <div class="table-responsive">

    <table class="table table-bordered table-dark text-center">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Email</th>
        <th scope="col">Password</th>
        <th scope="col">Account</th>
        <th scope="col">-</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
     <% usersList.forEach((user) => { %>
       <tr>
          <td class="login" ><%= user.login %></td>
          <td><%= user.password %></td>
          <td><%=  user.account %></td>
          <td class="text-right">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popupEditModal" ><a href="#" @click.prevent="userEdit(user)" style="color:white;">Edit</a></button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#popupDeleteModal" ><a href="#" @click.prevent="deleteUser(user)" style="color:white;">Delete</a></button>

    <!-- delete popup Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="popupDeleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
       <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;text-align:center;" >
        Confirmation delete <%= user.login %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
       </div>
        </div>
       </div>
        </div>
         <!-- edit popup Modal -->
       <div class="modal fade" id="popupEditModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="color:black;text-align:center;" >
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
                </td>
       </tr>
    <% }) %>

    </tbody>

    </table>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I get on the .ejs webpage a table with the users(everything is alright with the table).The table looks like:

```
  ID      Password       Account        -
  test     password1      acc1         ....
  test1    password2      acc2         ....
   ...       ...           ....         ....
  testn    passwordn+1    accn+1       .....
```

And as you can see both 2 divs of the modal popups are included in the forEach (from EJS) but when I click on the **delete** button I get : "Confirmation delete test" no matter what user id is,everytime I get "test" as ID and I think the modal gets the first id of the user ignoring my forEach() but I don't know why that...

Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: You can't repeat ID's in a page. They are unique by definition. Use the index of the loop to make the modal ID and modal targets unique

Comment: Wow...I completely forgot about the ID's...Thank you very much for help!